# Unable to start 'org.qtproject.example.testapp'

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5.1

I'm trying to deploy my Qt5 application on Android (Samsung S4). It compiles fine, but while deploying it stops on:

```
Starting debugger "QmlCppEngine" for ABI "arm-linux-android-elf-32bit
```

In Application Output I got:

```
Unable to start 'org.qtproject.example.testapp'. Debugging has failed
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: Also see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11071 and https://forum.qt.io/topic/28734/qt-5-1-and-android-unable-to-start-org-qtproject-example-myfirstandroidapp

Answer (score 1):

While viewing logcat report I found smth like:

"Failed dlopen(): somelib.so cannot find libQt5PrintSupport.so"

By temporary excluding somlib.so from project I was able to run application.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error turned out to be because the Android emulator was running out of space, so make sure to check if you have enough space on the emulator.

After uninstalling some apps to free up space the error disappeared.